# Probability that number taken from interval is 3 or 7 multiple

Tags: probability

There is an interval [17;1541]. What is probability that randomly chosen number is 3 **or** 7 multiple? I manage to count possibilities of each number like (1541-17)/3 and (1541-17)/7 respectively. But if I sum up these possibilities I will get that it can be both 3 **and** 7 multiple.

How should I count these possibilities?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use the *principle of inclusion - exclusion*. While counting the no. of multiples of 3 **or** 7, add no. of multiples of 3 to no. of multiples of 7, and from that subtract no. of multiples of 3 **and** 7.

Comment: How to count multiples of 3 and 7? Is it multiples of 21?

Comment: yes exactly because 3 and 7 are prime, else you would need to find their least common multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the set of integers which are multiples of $3$ within the interval and $B$ denote the set of integers which are multiples of $7$ within the interval.

It follows from the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) that:
$$n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)\color{#007777}{-n(A\cap B)}$$
Where $n$ represents the number in each set. It seems like from your explanation of what you've tried that you forgot to subtract $n(A\cap B)$ as i've indicated in blue.

Since $3$ and $7$ are prime, one may deduce that $A\cap B$ is the set of integers which are multiples of $21$ within the interval.

Once you find $n(A\cup B)$ use the fact that:

$$P(A\cup B)=\frac{n(A\cup B)}{n(U)}$$
Where $U$ represents the set of integers in the given interval and $P$ denotes the probability.